# How to write AND operator in spel for spring profiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-profiles

I am creating a bean in my Spring app. Currently using Spring 3.2 so fairly old. I have a bean xml file in which the root `<beans>` tag has the `profile` attribute. I would like the beans in this file to be created when the profile is not test or uat.. so something like `profile="!test && !uat"` etc.
I tried the following but spring does not support the `&&` operator so I currently have `profile="!test, !uat"`. From the official Spring documentation it says:

> If a profile is prefixed with the NOT operator '!', e.g.
>
> ```
>   <beans profile="p1,!p2">
> ```
>
> indicates that the  element should be parsed if profile "p1"
>   is active or  if profile "p2" is not active.

So clearly this wouldn't work in my case as I only want the bean to be created if the profile is not test and uat. Is there an operator i don't know about that I could use?

Comment: Can't you define what profile(s) you expect?

Comment: I have dev, test, uat, prod and demo profiles. I want this specific bean to be created on any profiles apart from test and uat. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [SpEL docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef):

Wrap the expression like the following `#{your_expression}`

SpEL supports the operators `&&, ||` and keywords `and, or`

Answer (score 0):

Choose the inclusive way and include all the wanted profiles (without the excluded)

```
<beans profile="dev,prod,demo">
```